# Setting cache control header for index.html(static files) | Java | jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I need to set Cache control headers for index.html which is served by jboss-eap6.4. I can not set this in java code as index.html(static content) does not call java code . 
I hope there must be a setting in Jboss standalone.xml to set cache control header for every static resource but not able to find one .

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510578/response-header-configuration-of-cache-control-time-for-js-files-in-wildfly-jbos` check this post

Comment: wildfly11.0 have a subsystem urn:jboss:domain:undertow . but this subsystem is not in jboss-eap6.4.